# Android KeyStore with 3DES

Tags: android, kotlin, android-keystore, 3des

Im trying save datas to android keystore with 3DES. But 3des algorithm is depracted. So i decided to write my own. But im getting "Attempt to get length of null array" null pointer exception.When i create that keystore with aes everythings fine. Am i skipping some parts? How can ı create android keystore with 3DES?

This is my encyrpt class :

```
class Encrypt {
private val TRANSFORMATION = "AES/GCM/NoPadding"
private val TRANSFORMATION = "DESede"
private val ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore"

private var encryption: ByteArray? = null
private var iv: ByteArray? = null

private var keyStore: KeyStore? = null

init {
    initKeyStore()
}

private fun initKeyStore() {
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE)
    keyStore!!.load(null)
}

fun encryptText(alias: String, textToEncrypt: String): ByteArray? {
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION)
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(alias))
    iv = cipher.iv
    return cipher.doFinal(textToEncrypt.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8"))).also { encryption = it }
}

private fun getSecretKey(alias: String): SecretKey {


    return generateOwnKey(alias).secretKey
}

fun getEncryption(): ByteArray? {
    return encryption
}

fun getIv(): ByteArray? {
    return iv
}

fun generateOwnKey(alias: String?): KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry {
    val myKey = SecretKeySpec(alias?.toByteArray(), "DESede")
    Log.i("type", myKey.algorithm)
    val secretKeyEntry = KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(myKey)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        keyStore?.setEntry(
            alias,
            KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(myKey),
            KeyProtection.Builder(KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                .build()
        )
    }
     return secretKeyEntry
```

}
}

and Decrypt class :

```
    private val TRANSFORMATION = "DESede"
private val ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore"

private var keyStore: KeyStore? = null

init {
    initKeyStore()
}

private fun initKeyStore() {
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE)
    keyStore!!.load(null)
}

fun decryptData(alias: String, encryptedData: ByteArray?, encryptionIv: ByteArray?): String? {
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION)

    val ivspec = IvParameterSpec(encryptionIv)
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(alias), ivspec)
    return String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedData), Charsets.UTF_8)
}

private fun getSecretKey(alias: String): SecretKey? {
    return (keyStore!!.getEntry(alias, null) as KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry).secretKey
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are generating an key outside of the AndroidKeystore and then import it. Why not directly generate a key inside AndoridKeystore so that it is never exposed? See this example: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec?hl=en#example:-aes-key-for-encryptiondecryption-in-gcm-mode

Comment: We want to set our custom keys, not generating directly. We want to generate keys with 3des and store it in keystore. For example getting string from service and generating key with this string using 3DES. And when we need this key we want to get from keystore and decrpyt with 3DES

Comment: But I would recommend to you to test the example adapted to 3DES and check if it works at all.

Comment: If you meaning Keyproperties.DES3_algorithm android key store is not containing that algorithm. But you mean anything else i skip on android page, can you link that example?

Comment: Click the link in my first comment?

Comment: That example with aes. When you change aes to 3des throwing this exception -> "no such algorithm: DESede for provider AndroidKeyStore"

Comment: Then you got your answer - not supported. So you can't use AndroidKeystore, but you can generate and save an AES key to encrypt the 3DES key saved in a file in the app-private data directory.